# DateTime ToString issue with formatting months with "mm" specifier

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a problem to get the correct format. I am expecting "2013/10", but instead I get "2013/00".

Why is that, and how can I fix this?

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2013-Oct-01");   
string str2 = dt.ToString("yyyy/mm");
```

Answer (score 28):

`mm` is for minute while `MM` is for month.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2013-Oct-01");
string str2 = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM");
```

See MSDN article *[DateTime.ToString méthode (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/zdtaw1bw.aspx)*.

For a more complete list:

```
// Create date time 2008-03-09 16:05:07.123
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 3, 9, 16, 5, 7, 123);

String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", dt);  // "8 08 008 2008"   year
String.Format("{0:M MM MMM MMMM}", dt);  // "3 03 Mar March"  month
String.Format("{0:d dd ddd dddd}", dt);  // "9 09 Sun Sunday" day
String.Format("{0:h hh H HH}",     dt);  // "4 04 16 16"      hour 12/24
String.Format("{0:m mm}",          dt);  // "5 05"            minute
String.Format("{0:s ss}",          dt);  // "7 07"            second
String.Format("{0:f ff fff ffff}", dt);  // "1 12 123 1230"   sec.fraction
String.Format("{0:F FF FFF FFFF}", dt);  // "1 12 123 123"    without zeroes
String.Format("{0:t tt}",          dt);  // "P PM"            A.M. or P.M.
String.Format("{0:z zz zzz}",      dt);  // "-6 -06 -06:00"   time zone
```

Comment: Now, I get "2013-10" which is still different. Where does the "-" come from.

Comment: The / separator is culture-dependent.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator

Comment: Great answer for giving explanations of each letter.  Full documentation is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: why is there the leading 0?

Answer (score 7):

`mm` is minutes. You need to use `MM` which is months:

```
var str2 = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM");
```

Answer (score 3):

`mm` is minutes. `MM` is month.  You are using the wrong field.