# Parsing dates in .NET (String to Date)

Tags: .net, vb.net, date

I am trying to parse a string into a date in .NET. I have the following code to do so:

```
Dim FromDateDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(FromDate, "mm/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I discovered however, that this line does not work properly when I Pass `08/18/2010` it parses it to `1/18/2010 12:08:00 AM` Can anyone tell me why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you see where the `08` went? See [DateTime ToString Issue with Formatting Months with "mm" specifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206359/datetime-tostring-issue-with-formatting-months-with-mm-specifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
Dim FromDateDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(FromDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The "mm" specifies *minutes*, "MM" is months.  See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for details.